Conducted Emissions from a PoE powered equipment according to En55032/CISPR32
I'm seeking clarification on Conducted Emissions measurements for a PoE powered device. I've  reviewed both the CISPR32 and CISPR 16-2-3 standards, yet I couldn't find specific guidance on the setup procedure. Additionally, I've consulted with two different lab technical managers, but unfortunately, there seems to be a lack of consensus regarding this issue
Configuration 1: This configuration was proposed by the lab, it is basically measuring the noise that is coming out of the PoE injector going towards the ethernet switch, their reasoning is that the data link between the EUT and the PoE injector is reserved and the noise there is not influencing any other device.
The configuration I had in mind is the following. Configuration 2
I would like to measure the noise coming out directly from the EUT. 


